# why is wish opening two windows instead of one?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

In Tcl/Tk, the source of file `/usr/bin/wan27`

```
#! /usr/bin/wish -f
set w .main
toplevel $w
wm title $w "FOO"
```

when issuing the command "wan27" from terminal (Linux/Debian/Ubuntu 10.04), it opens two windows, one with the title wan27 and the other one with the title FOO. I just want the FOO window to open. How can I fulfill that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/wish -f
wm title . "FOO"
```

Comment: cool, i was actually bumping a blog explaing widget path, so this is how to access current window! tx!

Comment: @fabjoa: It's not how to access the "current" window, it's how to access the default window. There's no real notion of "current" window, except maybe as relates to what window has focus.

Comment: @Bryan: Well, there's also the grab window and the window with the mouse pointer over it. But you're right, there's no real “current” window; GUIs don't work like that (which is what makes them hard to code for for most people).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that wish always creates a window named ".". So that is one window. You then create a second window with the `toplevel` command so now you have two.

Comment: i now get it! wish, automatically opens a window upon call. things are getting clearer with "ticle" poco a poco! Thanks,bryan!

Answer (score 1):

You can use also:

```
wm state . withdrawn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore `.` then you can just hide it: `wm iconify .`